# check the value in the and append with given value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my url I want to check autoplay is there and then replace the value.
In my iframe I have the url `https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640`
In that url I want to check the autoplay is there.If not need to append autoplay=1 with the url in playbutton click.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.playButton').click(function() {
       
        alert('play');
     $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].src += "&autoplay=1"; //need to check autoplay and append with src
        $("iframe").src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 1);
      });

      $(".close_icon").click(function() {
        alert('close');
        $("iframe").src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 0);
      });
    });
```

```html
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-active-slide">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640"></iframe>
</div>
    <div class="playButton">Play</div>
    <div class="close_icon">Close</div>
```

Comment: You could use iframe API instead of reloading the source and save bandwidth.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 1):

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.playButton').click(function() {
       
        alert('play');
        if(/\&autoplay\=\d/.test($('.flex-active-slide iframe')[0].src)) {
          $('.flex-active-slide iframe')[0].src = $('.flex-active-slide iframe')[0].src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 1);
        } else {
          $('.flex-active-slide iframe')[0].src += "&autoplay=1"; //need to check autoplay and append with src
        }
      });

      $(".close_icon").click(function() {
        alert('close');
        $("iframe")[0].src = $("iframe")[0].src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 0);
      });
    });
```

```html
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-active-slide">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640"></iframe>
</div>
    <div class="playButton">Play</div>
    <div class="close_icon">Close</div>
```

Comment: This code doesn't work since "src" is not defined in the line src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 0);

Comment: @Brad a little mistake. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try javascript string function indexOf to check autoplay existance

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.playButton').click(function() {       
         var src=$('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].src; 
        if(src.indexOf("autoplay") == -1){
           $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].src += "&autoplay=1"; //need to check autoplay and append with src
        }
        $("iframe").src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 1);
      });

      $(".close_icon").click(function() {
        alert('close');
        $("iframe").src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 0);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**I wrote up a little reliable function for you to use.**

Usage: `autoplayURL(url string, autoplayOn/Off bool);`

It returns the formatted string to set autoplay on or off.

By default, if you do not parse a second argument, autoplay will be on.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.playButton').click(function() {
  $("#youtube-iframe").attr("src", autoplayURL($("#youtube-iframe").attr("src")));
 });

 $(".close_icon").click(function() {
  $("#youtube-iframe").attr("src", autoplayURL($("#youtube-iframe").attr("src"), false));
 });
});
   
function autoplayURL(youtubeURL, autoplay) {
 // Set default value of autoplay
 if (autoplay === undefined)
  autoplay = true;

 autoplay = autoplay ? 1 : 0;

 // Remove trailing / from URL
 if (youtubeURL.endsWith("/"))
  youtubeURL = youtubeURL.substr(0, youtubeURL.length - 1);

 // Add ? to end of URL if it doesn't exist
 if (youtubeURL.indexOf('?') === -1) {
  youtubeURL += "?autoplay=" + autoplay;
  return youtubeURL;
 }

 var autoplayOpposite = autoplay === 0 ? 1 : 0;

 if (youtubeURL.indexOf('autoplay=') === -1) {
  // If URL does not contain 'autoplay=' then append to URL.
  youtubeURL += "&autoplay=" + autoplay;
 } else if (youtubeURL.indexOf('autoplay=' + autoplayOpposite) !== -1) {
  // If URL contains 'autoplay=0' then replace it with 'autoplay=1'.
  var firstPart = youtubeURL.substr(0, youtubeURL.indexOf('autoplay=' + autoplayOpposite));
  var lastPart = youtubeURL.substr(youtubeURL.indexOf('autoplay=' + autoplayOpposite)+10);
  youtubeURL = firstPart + "autoplay=" + autoplay + lastPart;
 }
 return youtubeURL;
}
```

```html
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-active-slide">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640" id="youtube-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
    <div class="playButton">Play</div>
    <div class="close_icon">Close</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Index of also you can use but if your url contains the word autoplay somewhere else then it may bomb example : "https://www.youtube.com/embed/**autoplay**C0DPdy98e4c?width=640". Try this (assuming you append autoplay at the end of the url always ) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.playButton').click(function() {

    alert('play');
    var srcArr = $('.flex-active-slide iframe')[0].src.split('&')
    var src = srcArr[srcArr.length-1];
 $('.flex-active-slide iframe')[0].src = src+"&autoplay=1"; 
    $("iframe")[0].src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 1);
  });

  $(".close_icon").click(function() {
    alert('close');
    $("iframe")[0].src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. The code is heavily commented so should be self explanitory but let me know if anything is unclear.

Hope it is useful to you.

```js
$('.playButton').click(function() {
 
 // get the current iframe url.
  var originalSrc = $('.flex-active-slide iframe').attr('src');
 
 //check if the autoplay=0 is part of the url.
  var autoplayPos = originalSrc.indexOf("?&autoplay=0")
  if (autoplayPos >= 0){
    // if it is lets remove it.
    originalSrc = originalSrc.substring(0,autoplayPos);
  } 
  
  // set the new url to our original url (without autoplay=0) with autoplay=1 apended
  var newSrc = originalSrc + "?&autoplay=1";
  
  // set the iframe source to the new url.
  $('.flex-active-slide iframe').attr('src', newSrc);
});

$(".close_icon").click(function() {
  // get the current iframe url.
  var originalSrc = $('.flex-active-slide iframe').attr('src')
  
  // we dont bother checking if auotplay is already there since the site will always start with it not there (i assume).
  
  // set new with, replace autoplay=1 with autoplay=0
  var newSrc = originalSrc.replace("?&autoplay=1", "?&autoplay=0");
  
  // set the iframe source to the new url.
  $('.flex-active-slide iframe').attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-active-slide">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="playButton">Play</div>
<div class="close_icon">Close</div>
```